# Converting string to DateTime with offset

Tags: c#, datetime

This is the string: `2007-08-31T06:59:40+02:00`

How do I convert it to `DateTime`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

DateTimeOffset also handles the time zone offset:

```
DateTimeOffset.Parse("2007-08-31T06:59:40+02:00")
```

or

```
DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("2007-08-31T06:59:40+02:00", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzzz"
                          ,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: but was not handled in user code: 'String '2018-07-25T14:51:16 00:00' was not recognized as a valid DateTime. DateTimeOffset mydate = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(reportRequest.fromDate, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss zzzz");

Answer (score 7):

You should use [`DateTimeOffset.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.parseexact.aspx) - you know the *exact* format you're expecting, and as this presumably has come from another computer rather than user input, it's a definite *error* if it fails. Likewise you should specify the invariant culture to indicate that this does not depend on the "current culture" of the executing thread.

```
var value = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(text,
                                      "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'sszzz",
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

`DateTimeOffset` is the type that accurately represents the information - `DateTime` would *have* to lose some of that information.

Answer (score 5):

Use `DateTime.Parse()`:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse ("2007-08-31T06:59:40+02:00")
```

Comment: Though the OP may want to use `DateTimeOffset` to preserve the offset.

Comment: Which 'wrong date' ? Providing details helps finding an answer quicker.

Comment: Bear in mind that DateTime will tell you the time in the local timezone (or UTC if you request), whereas the string you specified is in the +2:00 timezone. So a conversion will take place.

Answer (score 2):

You could use DateTimeOffset.TryParse Method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397029.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use `DateTimeOffset.Parse()`.

Then use either `DateTime` property or `DateTimeUtc` property to get a DateTime (but you should investigate if you could keep using DateTimeOffset.