# Convert time in string to UTC time?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Datetimes: Conversion for different time zones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682290/c-sharp-datetimes-conversion-for-different-time-zones)

I have a string like this "2012.12.04T08:35:00" that represents a time in the "W. Europe Standard Time" timezone.

Now, I want to convert this properly to a c# DateTime object in UTC time.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: [C# Datetimes: Conversion for different time zones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682290/c-sharp-datetimes-conversion-for-different-time-zones) tells you how to convert a time to (or, at least, from; you can extrapolate from this) UTC when you know what time zone it represents.

Comment: I know how to convert date times between time zones as soon as I have a proper DateTime object with the correct time zone. The problem is getting there first.

Comment: @Olav edited my answer to parse to a specific time zone offset.

Comment: `DateTime` has no concept of time-zone. They can have a `DateTimeKind` specified which allows you to say if the date is local or UTC.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`TimeZoneInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb495915.aspx) when converting between *specific* time zones:

```
TimeZoneInfo westInfo =
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time");

DateTime westTime = DateTime.Parse("2012.12.04T08:35:00");
DateTime utcTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(westTime, westInfo);
```

To address your confusion:

- `DateTime.Parse` as used here makes *no* assumptions about the timezone of the given value. IT stores it with a `DateTimeKind` of `Unspecified`.
- `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc` as used here *expects* an `Unspecified` datetime, reads it as if it is in the *explicitly specified* time zone, and converts it to UTC.

Comment: +1. This is the way to do it. I wish TimeZoneInfo had a method to find by the standard time zone [abbreviations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations).

Comment: You make the incorrect assumption that the code is running on a computer that is in the ""W. Europe Standard Time" time zone. This is not the case as the code is running in a Windows Azure datacenter.

Comment: @Olav I make no such assumption. If I'd been using `DateTime.ToUniersalTime` yes, but `TimeZoneInfo` is _there_ to convert time between non-local time zones. (This works on my machine, and I'm in a UTC zone, not in WEST.)

Comment: @ErenErsönmez extension method!

Comment: @James Not exactly _how_ it should be converted but _whether_ it should be converted; if it is `Local` but the specified timezone is not the local timezone, or `Utc` but the specified timezone is not UTC, it will throw rather than decide how to properly convert it.

Comment: @Rawling "*`TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc` as used here expects an `Unspecified` datetime*" - I would disagree (although probably just being pernickety!). The documentation states if the DateTime is already `Utc` no conversion is done, otherwise local time relative to the timezone used in the conversion is assumed.

Comment: @Rawling What is the result when you run it with this input "2012.12.04T08:35:00"?

Comment: @Olav I get a `DateTime` with Kind Utc, Year 2012, Month 12, Day 4, Hour 7, Minute 35, Second 0.

Comment: I removed my answer as it's pretty much identical to this one, and you beat me to it :)

Comment: @Rawling You are absolutely right the code works fine! I had another bug on my part that was screwing up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use DateTimeOffset.TryParse Method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397029.aspx

see post here

[Converting string to DateTime with offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270429/converting-string-to-datetime-with-offset/13270510#13270510)

Answer (score 0):

Reading from MSDN you should be able to parse the string into a DateTime object like this :

```
DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.Parse("2012.12.04T08:35:00");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx

You might have to change the `.` to `-`.

<strike>Then you should be albe to use this to get the UTC.</strike>

```
convertedDate.ToUniversalTime();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx

Edit (corrections from comments):

```
TimeZoneInfo tst = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time");

DateTime convertedTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(convertedDate, tst);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx

Comment: -1 `ToUniversal` will convert the datetime using the local time zone information i.e. the timezone of the machine itself.

Comment: The proposed answer does not solve the problem. My issue is how to get the string parsed into a DateTime object AND that the resulting object is in the "W. Europe Standard Time" time zone.

Comment: The above code actually works fine!

Answer (score -2):

You can use Convert.ToDateTime(). It should work.